# pcregrep missing from CentOS 7

Tags: centos, pcregrep

I have a fresh install of CentOS 8, and the pcre package is already installed.

However, the pcregrep command is not available and nowhere to be found on the filesystem. According to CentOS docs this should be in the 'pcre' package.  (See [centos.pkgs.org](https://centos.pkgs.org/8/centos-baseos-x86_64/pcre-8.42-4.el8.i686.rpm.html) )

> dnf provides */pcregrep
>
> dnf provides */pcre2grep

finds nothing.  BTW< pcre2 is also installed, but still no pcre2grep command available.

Can someone help my find 'pcregrep' command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pcre2` **libraries** are installed in the base of CentOS 8 by the package `pcre2`. The `pcre2grep` utility in CentOS 8 comes from the `pcre2-tools` package which comes from Atomic and not the base repo like it does in CentOS 7.

To install it in CentOS 8:

Add the Atomic repository:

```
yum install http://www6.atomicorp.com/channels/atomic/centos/8/x86_64/RPMS/atomic-release-1.0-21.el8.art.noarch.rpm
```

Install `pcre2-tools`:

yum install pcre2-tools

`pcre2grep` will then be installed:

```
/usr/bin/pcre2grep
```

Comment: atomic's pcres-tool needs atomic's pcre (which conflicts with CentOS's pcre, which is required for systemd).  So seems I'm stuck.  I'll experiment with grep -P

Comment: @TSG You want `pcre2-tools`, not `pcre-tools`.

Comment: pcre2-tools is not available for CentOS 8 (other than through atomic as mentioned above)

Comment: @TSG Exactly. That's why you get it from Atomic. `pcre2` and its related packages come from Atomic and has nothing to do with `pcre`. `pcre` comes from the BaseOS. I have both `pcre` and `pcre2` (via the Atomic Repo) and their related packages including `pcre2-tools` installed on my CentOS 8.1 system and there aren't any conflicts. They are completely separate.